# Table modes and backtracking in B-Prolog

Tags: prolog, b-prolog

Consider the program:

```
:- table cost(+, min).
cost(1, 0).
cost(1, 1).
cost(2, 1).
```

I expected that result to `cost(I, C).` would be I = 1, C = 0; I = 2, C = 1 - all possible input arguments with corresponding minimum results.

But I get only one:

```
cost(I, C).
I = 1
C = 0 ?;
no
```

But if I explicitly point to all possibilities for the input argument, I get what I want:

```
( I = 1 ; I = 2 ), cost(I, C).
I = 1
C = 0 ?;
I = 2
C = 1 ?;
no
```

Is it possible to get all combinations of input arguments with corresponding minimum results without explicitly enumerating all possible inputs?

Comment: Hopefully, [@nfz](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1890219/nfz) will answer!

Comment: Sergei, you are asking this question simultaneously on SO and in comp.lang.prolog - in this manner you will get half of the responses here and half there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago I found the answer right there in the B-Prolog manual: "Note that, **if table modes are not respected**, or if there is no bound for an optimized argument, **a program may give unexpected answers**".

Code in the question doesn't respect the "table cost(+, min)." modes and tries to use first cost/2 parameter as an output.

Answer (score 2):

A table declaration with an optimization mode (min or max) instructs the system to table one answer for each combination of the input arguments. You can give a cardinality limit to instruct the system to store multiple optimal answers. For example, you can give a declaration like:

```
:- table cost(+, min):3.
```

Then, the system will table up to 3 best answers, ordered by optimality, for each input. The limit is assumed to be 1 if not explicitly given.

The system does not store all answers. This is important because for dynamic programming problems, you only need to remember the current best answer to a sub-problem.

Neng-Fa Zhou

Comment: I can't use `table cost(+, min):3.`, because then for `cost(1, C).` I'll get 2 answers C = 0 and C = 1. 

I want to store only one min cost for every input parameter. But when I call `cost(I, C).` I expected to get this unique min cost for every input: I = 1, C = 0 ; I = 2, C = 1.